# Convert React page into a JSON, also be able to convert the same JSON back to React page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, forms, web

How can I convert a React page into a JSON so that once it is converted and saved I should be able to render back the same page with all the details?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';


const Form = () => {

    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(name);
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type='text' onChange={handleChange} />
            <br/>
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

For example I want to convert the above React component into JSON

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 0):

Although there is little reason to convert a react component to JSON, most things like server side rendering and sending different components over the web you can do while leaving the component in its original form, there are two ways you can do this. The first is much easier and it is to use the already existing [convert-react-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-react-to-json/v/0.2.4) library which provides easy to use functions that allow you to convert a react component to JSON and convert that JSON back to a component. However, if you want to design it to exactly meet your specification you will need to determine a scheme for each component JSON that has any data necessary to remake the component